# AJAX request failing each time I try to invoke php function from module

Tags: 7, ajax, hooks, navigation

I'm trying to invoke a AJAX request whenever someone clicks a download button on my drupal site.

In my module I have referenced the javascript file in the (my-module).info as follows:

```
scripts[] = js/my_module.js
```

my_module.js:

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".book-purchase-button").click(
    function(){
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/foo/ajax/tag',
      success: function(){
        alert("AJAX Call Successful!");
    },
      error: function(){
        alert("AJAX Call Failed!!");
    }
        });
    });  
  });
})(jQuery);
```

I figured I could do a menu callback to capture the AJAX request based on the url

my_module.module:

```
/*
*    Implements hook_menu().
*/
function my_module_menu()
{
  $items = array();
  $items['/foo/ajax/tag'] = array(
    'title' => '',
    'page callback' => 'my_module_tag_user',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'access callback' => TRUE, // allows access to any user
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}
```

But for some reason the AJAX request keeps alerting me that the ajax call has failed... Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routes don't have leading slashes:

```
$items['foo/ajax/tag'] = array(
```

Clear caches, and assuming the callback function exists and writes something to the buffer, it'll start working.

Comment: You are a lifesaver! Everything works correctly now!